# ¿Como puedo resolver este codigo con tkinter y clases en python?

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Estoy tomando un curso de python con tkinter, pero al crear una calculadora sin clases el programa funciona correctamente, y al convertirlo en una estructura con clases me marca que tengo error en la parte de la creación del objeto y en la definición de la funcion **init**_, cabe mencionar que al profesor si le funciona pero en mi caso no. ya me trate de comunicar con el, pero no contesta ajjaja  No se si me pudieran ayudar de favor, se los agradeceria mucho. Este es el codigo que no me esta funcionando estare al pendiente.

```
"""
CALCULADORA:
- Dos campos de texto
- 4 botones para las operaciones
- Mostrar el resultado en una alerta
"""
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 

class Calculadora: 

    def __init__(self,alertas):
        self.numero1= StringVar()
        self.numero2= StringVar()
        self.resultado= StringVar()
        self.alertas= alertas

    def cFloat(self,numero):
        try:
            result= float(numero)
        except:
            result=0
            self.alertas.showerror("Error", "Introduce bien los datos")
        
        return result 

    def sumar(self):
        
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) + self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()
    
    def restar(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) - self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()

    def multiplicar(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) * self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()

    def dividir(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) / self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()

    def mostrarResultado(self):
        self.alertas.showinfo("Resultado", f"El resultado de la operación es:  {self.resultado.get()}")
        self.numero1.set("")
        self.numero2.set("")

calculadora= Calculadora(messagebox)

ventana= Tk()
ventana.title("Ejercicio completo con tkinter | Gustavo Osorno Flores ")
ventana.geometry("400x400")
ventana.config(
    bd=50
)

marco = Frame(ventana, width=300, height=200)
marco.config(
    padx=15,
    pady=15,
    bd=5,
    relief=SOLID
)
marco.pack(side=TOP, anchor=CENTER)
marco.pack_propagate(False)

Label(marco, text="Primer número: ").pack()
Entry(marco, textvariable=calculadora.numero1,justify="center").pack()

Label(marco, text="Segundo número: ").pack()
Entry(marco, textvariable=calculadora.numero2,justify="center").pack()

Label(marco, text="").pack()

Button(marco,text="Sumar", command=calculadora.sumar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
Button(marco,text="Restar",command=calculadora.restar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
Button(marco,text="Multiplicar", command=calculadora.multiplicar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
Button(marco,text="Dividir", command=calculadora.dividir).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES )

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor no resumas los errores; pon la traza de error completa EN la pregunta. Puedes [edit] y hacerlo.

Comment: Las variables de control (como stringvars) tienen que crearse luego de la ventana (Tk). La clase calculadora al iniciarse crea stringvars. Por lo tanto, la solucion es simplemente crear la calculadora LUEGO de crear la ventana.